# Public key encryption with modified private key requried

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want the encryptor to be able to choose a key X and using it and the public key, he will be able to encrypt a message m. Then I get the key X and using the matching private key I'm able to generate another key Y, which using it anyone can decrypt messages encrypted with X, and only with it. Is such a cryptosystem possible, still being secure? If so, how?

Something like this:

[image: An image illustrating the crytosystem]

Comment: It is impossible to say whether this is secure, without knowing the context and the threat model. Secure against what?

Comment: Secure against someone getting x-keys, and being able to decrypt other x-s.

Comment: Have you considered encrypting both symmetrically and asymetrically? E.g. `encrypt=AES(x, RSA(pub, msg))`.

Comment: But than what would be the X-key? It would have to be the RSA private key, and if someone got it he can decrypt all x-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to do this.

**RSA-KEM**

**The sender**

1. RSA-KEM select a uniform random integer `x` between `2` and `n-1`, where `n` is the RSA modulus with at least `n>=2^2048`.
2. Use HKDK to derive a 128, 192, or 256 it key `k`  `k = KDF(x)`
3. Encrypt the data with `(c,tag) =AES-GCM_ENC(k, message)`
4. Encrypt the $x$ with the receivers public key `K = RSA_enc(pk,x)`
5. Send `(K,c,tag)` pair to the receviver.

**The receiver**

1. Decrypt the `x` with `k = RSA_DEC(priv,K)`
2. Use HKDK to derive a 128, 192, or 256 it key `k`  `k = KDF(x)`
3. Decrypt the data with `(message,tag) =AES-GCM_DEC(k, c)`

   1. If the tag doesn't match, stop!!!

**Some notes:**

- The AES-GCM is an Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data (AEAD) that provides confidentiality, integrity, and authentication.
- [RSA-KEM is not a standard](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83470/18298). If one ever wants to use RSA, this is the way.
- Although the [AES-128 is secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76746/18298) even after 20 years of research. you can use AES-256 with at most %40 speed penalty. This will also protect from the [Quantum computers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75241/18298).
- [AES-GCM has many pitfalls for correctly use](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/84359/18298), using Chacha20-poly1305 is easier.
- AES-GCM-SIV can be used for protection against [nonce misuse](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82105/18298).

**NaCl**

Use the existing libraries of the NaCl. This library has authenticated encryption with the public key; [The Crypto-Box](http://Authenticated%20encryption). Implemented for various languages.

**ECIES**

This is [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](http://Elliptic%20Curve%20Integrated%20Encryption%20Scheme%20(ECIES)). After the key exchange use AES-GCM-SIV or Chacha20-Poly1305.

Comment: But then couldn't someone who has X and a message encrypted using it find its k and use it to decrypt?

Comment: Find my private key to decrypt `x`? Life doesn't work in this way. RSA is based on the hardness of factoring... If everything is used properly, like using a good random number generator for the key generator, good RSA modulus size like > 2048 you will be fine. The current factoring recond is [829 bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge).  So, tell us who can do this to RSA-2048 other than hacking or the quantum computer ( long story).

Comment: But if another person is getting a random `x`, can't they just decrypt the message with AES (using KDF(x))?

Comment: The probability of hitting `x` by uniform random selection is `1/2^128` for 128-bit key. You have more chance of getting hit by lightning. Use AES 256 and far `1/2^256`. You should check about big numbers. I can see that this area is not your subject, and you are asking simple questions that can only be understood if you know math and probability. Even [AES-128 is secure after 20 years](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76746/18298).

Comment: oh wait, I misunderstood your answer. Now I see you meant that you publish the encrypted value and not the value you randomize. The names confused me a little. Thanks!

Comment: Why do we need to publish our key material :). It is the most precious item in the Cryptography that must be kept secret and protected all the time and should be erased after use. These are common practices in Cryptography.